# BigQuery Unnest based on a condition + cross join

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

Consider the following schema for monthly purchases, where items and payment are nested columns:

```
user      STRING
items     RECORD
     class      STRING 
     spent      INT 
payment RECORD 
     method  STRING
```

e.g. MWE (nested items & payment)

```
User     items            payment    
Joe   class spent         method
       fruit  45       Direct Debit 
       drinks 10       Credit Card 
       fish   20
       drugs  35
```

I'd like to unnest both the field `items` and `payment` but in different ways:

1. Restrict the field 'items' to those ones containing class='fruit' or class='drink' and unstack the values into columns
2. Regular cross join user - payment methods

One possible solution would be to split into two steps:

```
with 

payments as (
select user, pay.method
from table
cross join table.payments as pay 
) 

, items_fruit as (
select user, items.spent as spent_fruit 
from table 
cross join table.items as items
where items.class IN ('fruit')
) 

, items_drinks as (
select user, items.spent as spent_drinks
from table 
cross join table.items as items
where items.class IN ('drinks')
) 


select *
from payments 
INNER JOIN items_fruit using(user) 
INNER JOIN items_drinks using(user)
```

i.e. the outcome of the operation looking like below. However, it doesn't seem elegant nor efficient, what is the best way to achieve it?

```
user    payment     spent_fruit   spent_drinks 
Joe   Direct Debit      45             10
Joe   Credit Card       45             10
```

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result, so we can actually help you!

Comment: Question edited with example table and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select * from (
  select user, class, spent, method as payment
  from your_table t, t.items, t.payment 
)
pivot (sum(spent) as spent for class in ('fruit', 'drinks'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]